# How to set latest instance to parent when creating new object from has_one association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in the models:

```
*bar.rb*
belongs_to: foo 

*foo.rb*
has_one :bar
```

We have a Foo. And lets say a Bar is created `bar.create(foo_id: foo.id)`, so after that we have `foo.bar` pointing to the new instance object of Bar. Now I want to know how can i create new Bar and update Foo, so after `foo.bar` it shows the latest Bar created?

What I tried:

`Bar.create(foo_id: foo.id)` Sometimes it shows the latest after running `foo.bar`, sometimes it doesn't and thats the issue btw.

`Foo.update(bar: new_bar)` Says ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to remove the existing associated foo. The record failed to save after its foreign key was set to nil.)

In the model when I try and debug it with `after_create :update_bar_foo_latest` and in this method: `puts bar.foo` its always the latest instance.. but still when I check in the Database its the old foo.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What rails version are you on?

Comment: rails 6.0.3.4, I found some way like this, don't know if it is the right approach tho..
before_create ->
`foo.where('bar_id = ?', bar.id).where.not(id: bar.foo.id).destroy_all`, something like this, this
This works for now I guess, but would like to know if there is other solution
Thank you